# Are there diminishing returns on crowd control abilities?

Tags: diablo-iii

Are there diminishing returns on crowd control abilities such as Blind?

I was wondering if 4 monks with [Blinding Flash](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/blinding-flash) could keep mobs permanently stunned, since the skill can be runed to blind for 4 seconds, and the cooldown is 15 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major factors in determining how effective CC is. The first is mob type. Rares and Champion Packs tend to resist the magnitude of CC effects - this is even explicitly stated on Blinding Flash's tooltip (elites get a chance to miss, rather than being blinded). Likewise, bosses are also highly resistant to CC. Diablo, for instance, can basically ignore the snare from a Wizard's Blizzard.

The other factor is difficulty - CC effects last less long on higher difficulties. At Hell and Inferno, stuns, knockbacks, and the like sometimes simply *fail* to occur in the first place.

So to answer your posed scenario - sure, 4 monks could permanently CC a group of Normal mobs - but a group of mobs in Normal difficulty aren't something you'd *need* to permanently CC in the first place.

Comment: What exactly is CC?

Comment: CC is a generic term used in video games that reference a character ability to generally incapacitate other players or computer control characters in game. It stands for crowd control.

Comment: So... your answer is No, there are no diminishing returns on crowd control. Using the same CC ability on a mob repeatedly does not cause the monster to become immune to the ability, or to decrease the duration of the ability :)

Comment: There are no diminishing returns, but it's unlikely you can abuse that fact the way you were hoping.